# How to get selection of iFrame?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, getselection

The following code alerts a message with the text selected on the current page, if viewing with chrome at least:

```
alert(window.getSelection());
```

But how can I get this to work even when the selection is text that is inside an iFrame? (the iFrame contents is of the same domain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.getSelection();
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Actually, it seems in Chrome you want to use ...contentDocument.getSelection() instead.